# Error in Firefox only: unrecognized expression: [data-toggle='tooltip']

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my HTML:

```
<img class="icon-landpage pull-left" src="/Assets/img/sistemas/SABT.png" alt="Sistema de XXXXXYYYY">

<h1>XXXXyyyy <small><em>Versão: 1.0</em></small></h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum at sapien porta, eleifend nunc at, molestie mi. Donec cursus, dolor eget eleifend dignissim, nibh eros pharetra nunc, sit amet facilisis lacus sapien in augue.</p>
<p class="text-right">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="ECU003_Autenticar_Usuario_Acesso.html">Acessar</a>
    <a class="btn" href="ECU003_Autenticar_Usuario_Lista_Sistema.html">Voltar</a>
</p>
```

When I initialize the tootip like this:

```
$('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Firefox throws an error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-toggle='tooltip'    
throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
jquery-1.8.2.js (linha 4679)**strong text**
```

Comment: can you post your whole html? Are you trying to insert a tooltip somewhere?

Comment: When i Active the tooltip in JS $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip(); nothing works on Firefox!

Comment: Here's a fiddle for demonstration. http://jsfiddle.net/CX6Rr/1 However, you don't have any elements in your code that match your jQuery selector.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with `rel` and `data-original-title` values in place. The jQuery works fine in Firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/CX6Rr/3

Comment: does not work yet! :(